# Apps Script - count rows in variable range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

With Apps Script, I need to copy a section of a sheet to another area, with the start and end cells of the range based on variable inputs. Is there any built in function to count the number of rows in this variable-sized range?

I've searched all over and can't find any way to get this seemingly simple info for a defined range.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

.getValues() on a Range object returns a regular javascript array of arrays, which you can measure with .length.

Comment: Thanks! So simple I'm embarrassed I didn't see it.

Comment: I've been there too